# Converting C# cryptography to Java

Tags: java, c#, encryption, aes, rijndael

I have been tasked with converting a C# cryptography method to Java and am stuck. I know the C# codes works, but I am having trouble getting my Java code to work.

Here is the C# code:

```
private const int Nb = 4; // Legal values:  4 = 128-bit blocks

public static void Decrypt(byte[] input, Stream output)
    { 
        var s1 = new MemoryStream(input);
        const int BufferSize = 1024;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BufferSize];

        input.Read(buffer, 0, 4);
        int pad = buffer[3];

        RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
        rijndael.BlockSize = Nb * 32;
        rijndael.KeySize = buffer[1] * 32;

        rijndael.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        rijndael.Padding = PaddingMode.None;

        byte[] key = GetKey(buffer[1]);
        ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, GetIV());

        int bytes;
        while ((bytes = input.Read(buffer, 0, BufferSize)) > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i += rijndael.BlockSize)
            {
                decryptor.TransformBlock(buffer, i, rijndael.BlockSize, buffer, i);
            }
            output.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
        }
        output.SetLength(output.Length - pad - 4);
    }
```

And here is my attempt in Java so far:

```
public static String decrypt(byte[] input) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/NoPadding");
    byte[] key = getKey(input[1]);
    SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, 0, key.length, "AES/ECB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(getIV()));
    // remove first 4 since C# code reads past those
    byte[] finalDecoded = Arrays.copyOfRange(input, 4, input.length);
    byte[] decryptedVal = cipher.doFinal(finalDecoded);
    return new String(decryptedVal);
}
```

Some More Information

- For `GetIV` and `GetKey`, I can guarantee that the results in java are the same (I have compared every byte), but I am not including those methods because I believe that is sensitive information. I can also guarantee that the input byte[] is identical and (redundantly) the same length.
- **Debugging attempts:** The current error in Java is `ECB mode cannot use IV`.

  - When I remove this code : `new IvParameterSpec(getIV())` I get this error: `Wrong algorithm: AES or Rijndael required`
  - If I change the algorithm to only `AES` or only `Rijndael` I get this error: `Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher`. The input length starting is `424` and `420` after reading past/removing the first 4 bytes. I have verified that the input bytes are the same for Java and C#.

Where am I going wrong in the Java code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting the error `ECB mode cannot use IV` because ECB doesn't perform chaining, so IV is meaningless. The difference is Java throws an error whereas C# just ignores the IV.

> When I remove this code : `new IvParameterSpec(getIV())` I get this error: `Wrong algorithm:`**`AES or Rijndael`**`required`
>
> If I change the algorithm to only AES or only Rijndael I get this error: `Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with` **`padded cipher.`**

You had the right idea, but you went too far. This error is only to do with the `SecretKeySpec`, which doesn't care about the mode, but just the algorithm. `Cipher` is where you specify mode. Also, Rijndael and AES aren't quite the same thing.

So start by changing the first few lines to this:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("Rijndael/ECB/NoPadding");
byte[] key = getKey(input[1]);
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, 0, key.length, "Rijndael");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
```

Note that since you're using the entire `key` you don't need the offset and length arguments, so you can just do

```
SecretKey secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "Rijndael");
```

---

The original C# code has some not-so-obvious behavior:

```
while ((bytes = input.Read(buffer, 0, BufferSize)) > 0)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes; i += rijndael.BlockSize)
    {
        decryptor.TransformBlock(buffer, i, rijndael.BlockSize, buffer, i);
    }
    output.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
}
```

When the loop gets to the end of the `input`, it will copy however much is left of it into `buffer`. Unless the last `Read` was exactly 1024 bytes, there will be residue from the previous loop (or from initialization if it gets the whole `input` with one `Read` operation) after the end of the input.

The inner loop decrypts one 16-byte block at a time. In the case of your 420-byte example, the last block will consist of the remaining 4 bytes of input **and 12 more bytes of garbage**. But it's okay because the `output.Write` only writes `bytes` number of bytes to truncate the garbage. You will have to replicate this behavior in your Java code.

---

*Side note: do you absolutely have to use ECB? It's not very secure...*

Comment: Thank you so much. When I applied your changes, I got this error `Input length not multiple of 16 bytes`. Which is similar to the other error I was getting except it doesn't say anything about padding.

Comment: I tried removing the last 4 bytes of the input array (as well as the first 4) since the last 4 are padding to make the length a multiple of 16 and it pretty much worked, there are just some weird characters at the end of the decrypted string...

Comment: I forgot to mention, you also do not truncate the final result like the original C# does (`output.SetLength(output.Length - pad - 4);`) so that could affect your results too.

Comment: Yeah, I that not so obvious behavior was the last piece. Once I got converted that to Java it worked! Thanks again!!